# React ref current scrollLeft not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone explain why this code returns the same value in the two logs?

Visually the change is applied.

```html
console.log(refer.current.scrollLeft);
refer.current.scrollLeft += scrollOffset;
console.log(refer.current.scrollLeft);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element the ref is attached to has `scrollBehavior: smooth` applied to it then the value doesn't update instantaneously.